# Multiple const in one variable declaration

Tags: c, constants, ansi-c

A colleague of mine is going a bit nuts with const in ANSI C and I wanted to know what you guys thought about it. He writes stuff like this for example:

```
const uint8* const pt_data
```

I understand where he's going with this but for me it makes the reading and maintainability harder with all these const everywhere.

Comment: Do you have a question about this? This site is not intended for voicing your opinion, but for getting objective answers to questions.

Comment: Thanks for your input... question answered below

Comment: Does your colleague do this in header files as well as in the implementation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a `const` pointer pointing to `const` data.

- The first `const` prevents `*pt_data = 10;`
- The second `const` prevents `pt_data = stuff;`

It looks like it can be pretty legitimate.

Comment: It is also good programming practice. Get the compiler to prevent any bugs from occuring in the first place is a lot cheaper.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, it can be. However, after a certain threshold I found going all const-mad simply makes your life harder. But yes, it's generally useful and self-documenting.

Comment: That's what I'm feeling also, I mean I understand the usefulness but the guy puts const EVERYWHERE so it makes code harder to read

Comment: Personally I do not find the code harder to read - guess all those years programming to strict standards set up by ESA have taught me that. I rather the compiler picks up a potential bug before it gets shipped.

Comment: @Leo: It probably makes his code *hard to read* and also *hard to break*, If he knows his variable is never meant to be modified,it makes sense that he uses `const`, it makes users of his code aware that the variable was not meant to be changed,and they should not modify it.Also, using the `const` allows additional opportunity to implement optimizations, though this is debatable and may depend and vary on a case by case basis.

Comment: Hi guys, I found this function declaration : `int qemu_show_nic_models(const char *arg, const char *const *models)` and I guess the second argument is then const char pointer to the const pointer. For a const pointer that is pointed to by the const pointer we place `const *` not `const`? Hmm.. interesting..

Answer (score 9):

`const` always refers to the word on its right, except if it is at the end of the line, where it refers to the item itself (in higher level languages)

```
const char* str; //This is a pointer to read-only char data
                 //Read as to (const char)* str;
                 //Thus :
                 //   *str = 'a';
                 //Is forbidden

char* const str; //This is a read-only pointer to a char data
                 //Read as char* (const str);
                 //Thus :
                 //   str = &a;
                 //Is forbidden

const char* const str; //This is a read-only pointer to read-only char data
                       //Read as (const char)* (const str);
                       //Thus :
                       //    str = &a
                       //  and
                       //    *str = 'a';
                       //Is forbidden
```

You should always initialize those pointers when declaring them (Except if they're a parameter)

`const` keyword is great at ensuring something will not be modified, and also tells the developper it should not. For example `int strlen(const char* str)` tells you the `char` data in your string will not be modified whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

It is a constant pointer to an constant data.
it means you cannot change the data(whose address `pt_data` stores) and also cannot change the pointer(`pt_data`) to point to something else(some other address).

He probably needs it that way.

Answer (score 4):

If you start at the variable name, and going counter-clockwise, `pt_data` is a `const` pointer to `uint8` which is `const`.

See the following crude ASCII image:

```
  ,--------------------------------.
  |                                |
  |     ,------------------------. |
  |     |                        | |
  |     |   ,------------------. | |
  |     |   |                  | | |
  |     |   |    ,-----------. | | |
  |     |   |    |           | | | |
const uint8 * const pt_data; | | | |
        |   |    |     |     | | | |
        |   |    |     `-----' | | |
        |   |    |             | | |
        |   |    `-------------' | |
        |   |                    | |
        |   `--------------------' |
        |                          |
        `--------------------------'
```

Ever since I saw this scheme in an old C book many years ago, it has helped me understand complex declarations.

Comment: This is David Anderson's [clockwise or spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: @Als Seems I got the direction wrong, but at least now I have somewhere to point when describing it. Thanks! :)